Assignment of Teams in Google App Scripts
I wrote the below code to pick up samples from the master sheet to do random audit. Everything was perfect but i wanted to assign the first half to Team A and second half to Team B but this code is randomly assigning them and i need them in order. Can you help with the logic please? this would pickup the random cases based on Location, type and status.
ffunction auditCases() {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Master Sheet");
 var auditSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Audit sheet");


 // Clear previous data in the audit sheet
 auditSheet.clear();


 var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
 var headers = data[0];


 // Get the columns indices based on headers
 var typeIndex = headers.indexOf("Type");
 var locationIndex = headers.indexOf("Location");
 var statusIndex = headers.indexOf("Status");
 var monthIndex = headers.indexOf("Month Number");
 var yearIndex = headers.indexOf("Year");


 // Prompt user for input
 var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
 var monthResponse = ui.prompt("Enter Month Number (1-12)", ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
 if (monthResponse.getSelectedButton() !== ui.Button.OK) {
   return; // Exit if cancel or close is pressed
 }
 var monthNumber = parseInt(monthResponse.getResponseText().trim(), 10);


 // Validate month number
 if (isNaN(monthNumber) || monthNumber < 1 || monthNumber > 12) {
   ui.alert("Invalid month number. Please enter a number between 1 and 12.");
   return;
 }


 var yearResponse = ui.prompt("Enter Year (e.g., 2024)", ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
 if (yearResponse.getSelectedButton() !== ui.Button.OK) {
   return; // Exit if cancel or close is pressed
 }
 var year = yearResponse.getResponseText().trim();


 // Filter data based on month and year
 var filteredData = data.filter(function(row, index) {
   if (index === 0) return false; // Skip header row
   return row[monthIndex] == monthNumber && row[yearIndex] == year;
 });


 // Log filtered data for debugging
 Logger.log(filteredData);


 if (filteredData.length === 0) {
   ui.alert('No data found for the specified month and year.');
   return;
 }


 // Separate professional and personal cases
 var professionalCases = filteredData.filter(function(row) {
   return row[typeIndex] === "Professional";
 });


 var personalCases = filteredData.filter(function(row) {
   return row[typeIndex] === "Personal";
 });


 // Calculate number of cases to select
 var totalCases = filteredData.length;
 var personalCasesToAudit = Math.min(Math.ceil(totalCases * 0.1), 30); // 10% of personal cases or max 30
 var professionalCasesToAudit = Math.min(Math.ceil(totalCases * 0.05), 10); // 5% of professional cases or max 10


 // Function to get random samples from an array
 function getRandomSamples(arr, num) {
   var result = [];
   var len = arr.length;
   var taken = new Array(len);
   var minNum = Math.min(num, len); // Ensure we don't take more than available


   if (minNum > len) {
     throw new RangeError("getRandomSamples: more elements taken than available");
   }


   while (result.length < minNum) {
     var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * len);
     if (!taken[x]) {
       result.push(arr[x]);
       taken[x] = true;
     }
   }


   return result;
 }


 // Get random samples for professional cases
 var professionalAuditSamples = getRandomSamples(professionalCases, professionalCasesToAudit);


 // Get random samples for personal cases
var personalAuditSamples = getRandomSamples(personalCases, personalCasesToAudit);


 // Shuffle audit samples
 professionalAuditSamples.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5);
 personalAuditSamples.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5);


 // Distribute samples equally between Team A and Team B
 var teamA = [];
 var teamB = [];


 var halfProfIndex = Math.ceil(professionalAuditSamples.length / 2);
 var halfPersIndex = Math.ceil(personalAuditSamples.length / 2);


 teamA = teamA.concat(professionalAuditSamples.slice(0, halfProfIndex));
 teamA = teamA.concat(personalAuditSamples.slice(0, halfPersIndex));


 teamB = teamB.concat(professionalAuditSamples.slice(halfProfIndex));
 teamB = teamB.concat(personalAuditSamples.slice(halfPersIndex));


 // Add header to the audit sheet
 auditSheet.appendRow(headers);


 // Function to append rows to audit sheet
 function appendRowsToAuditSheet(rows) {
   rows.forEach(function(row) {
     auditSheet.appendRow(row);
   });
 }


 // Add samples to teams
 appendRowsToAuditSheet(teamA);
 appendRowsToAuditSheet(teamB);


 ui.alert('Audit samples generated and distributed to Team A and Team B.');
}


I removed the tags [[tag:java]] and [[tag:vba]] because I see nowhere that these languages are used. If they are, you should provide more details where and how. Tags are supposed to attract experts and if, say, a Java programmer looks at this post, I don't think they would be able to help with their Java knowledge.

To help you get a more accurate answer, it would be beneficial if you could provide a minimal, reproducible example, such as a dummy sheet with sample data for replication purposes. This would allow the community to better understand your problem and provide targeted solutions. If you're unsure, please refer to Stack Overflow Guide on Creating a Minimal, Reproducible Example. Including a reproducible example will greatly increase your chances of receiving a helpful response.

This part is randomly shuffling the order of the array and it's being split in half by the subsequent logic. Doesn't it make sense to take this part out if you want it in the original order?
 // Shuffle audit samples
 professionalAuditSamples.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5);
 personalAuditSamples.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5);

